# Do you need to translate a parent consent for travelling (flying) abroad?

Tags: air-travel, uk, customs-and-immigration, airports, children

My parents got me a consent so I could travel to UK this summer. Do I need to have it translated into English?

Comment: Preferably yes. Will be easier on the any officials who you meet and who demand it. Also I am saying this because UK visa rules demand English language versions of supporting documents

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a translated version of the letter as well, as UK immigration require all the foreign language document should be translated into English ,

here is the reference,

https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by
a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office. Each
translated document must contain:

- confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of the original
  document
- the date of the translation
- the translator's full name and signature
- the translator's contact details

Under 18s... If travelling unaccompanied or with someone other than your parent(s) you should
provide:

- a signed letter from your parent(s) confirming details of anyone accompanying
  you, and details of care and accommodation arranged in the UK
- a copy of your parent(s) or legal guardian’s biographical page of their passport,
  which includes their signature and passport number if your parent(s) do not
  have a passport then you must provide another official document which bears
  their signature

Comment: We discourage link only answers as links might break (in fact, the UK immigration pages are notorious for doing this) and so I copied the relevant information into your answer.

Comment: I would like to see the immigration officer's face if you presented them with a parental consent letter in Welsh!